# Instrument control with python - losing connection

Tags: python, windows, instrumentation, pyvisa

I am a researcher controlling my lab remotely. I use python to connect to all my instruments, with each instrument being an instance of a class, such as:

```
Class Motor():

   def setup():
       establish connection with this guy

   def move(x):
       move this guy

   def close():
      close this guy

My_motor = Motor()
```

My problem is, I often lose connection with my remote PC, accidentally re-run code or forget to close an instrument, causing my instruments instance to be lost, meaning I have no way of re-establishing a connection.

The solution I have so far is to disable-enable the device in Device Manager, though I often have to restart my computer to do so ^ ^.

Does anyone have a solution? A further complication is my university IT guys are extremely prohibitive of what software can be installed so possible routes such as USBDEVIEW are likely ruled out.

A more concrete example:
I connect to the resource located at ASRL2

```
import pyvisa
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
inst = rm.open_resource('ASRL2::INSTR')
```

My terminal dies, computer restarts or I override my instance inst:

```
inst = 'Random thing'
```

Now I have no way of closing the original connection, or reestablishing a new one. In pyvisa this would give the VisaIOError:

```
VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_RSRC_BUSY (-1073807246): The resource is valid, but VISA cannot currently access it.
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't just keep trying to connect to the dead end when connection drops? Put some try/except blocks around the part of the code that might throw an exception when connection drops, and retry to connect a fixed number of times or endlessly with the endpoint.

Comment: I have added a wee bit more explanation at the bottom of my question. 
I think the main problem is that I don't actually lose connection, I lose the instance of the connection.

Comment: Try using a context manager that can store the state of an instance when the connection is closed, will that work ???

Comment: Ah thats intresting, if I use:
`
Class Instrument():
def __enter__(self):
     start connection

def __exit__(self):
     kill connection

with instrument as inst:
`

Will give it a try :)